# When is work place politics a good thing?

Tags: politics

I’ve heard office politics could be a good thing, for example those who unofficially gain more power have a trait about them which naturally makes them good leaders or suited for the job they now have. This seems very theoretical. It’s been my observation that the more office politics going on, the more mistreatment of staff there is. When is it that office politics is a good or bad thing? Why does it often lead to bullying?

An example of the office politics I'm talking about is this: someone feeling like they haven't had enough work so they throw out an old lamp someone uses because "it is unsafe" and they apologize to the person explaining they are just keeping people safe.

An example of bad work place politics: I had a manager who told a story. He said a long time ago when someone retired she sent all the people in the company a goodbye note written on paper. Though he never met her, he got a note. He replied to her saying "goodbye but you wasted a lot of paper and I don't know you" and he got in trouble. My manager said about himself "back then I didn't know work place politics but I learned my lesson and now always have them in mind". I think this is a misunderstanding of workplace politics.

Comment: I don't think it is ever a _GOOD_ thing. It may be a necessary thing, or even the least-bad thing. Realistically, "politics" is wired into our brains as pack/troupe behavior,  and unless we actively try to avoid it that just going to happen.  All you can do is try to find a team that truly believes in positive sum games.

Comment: This would depend on your definition of "office politics". Whenever it's used, it's typically in a derogatory fashion and therefore not a good thing. But you could call basic management and C-level meetings politics if you'd be so inclined. Voting to close as opinion-based and because this doesn't really fit a Q&A format.

Comment: @JoeT - I voted to reopen.  You could probably add some more info to the question.   However closing your question is obnoxious because 80% of the questions on this site are primarily opinion based.  Sorry the site isn't moderated better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Plato said something like -  those who refuse to partake in politics will be ruled by inferior people.

My personal take is that if a company is ran correctly that politics would be non-existent.  All decisions and promotions should be made for the good of the company. The problems we have at most companies and certainly almost all medium and large companies are:

- the goals of the company aren't defined well, which leads to ambiguity
- the company has clear goals, but not the expertise on staff that understands even remotely how to reach them.
- the company's goals and the best way to get to them clearly conflict with personal goals of staff.  You could have a really smart head of an engineering department in Brazil that understands that combining all staff in South America would be best for company.  But maybe he would never recommend this because he may lose his job.

So there are two things we can never get rid of that contaminates this environment:

1. Emotion:  Since there aren't clear goals or some sort of ambiguity people are left more freedom as there probably won't be repercussions based on something undefined.  They will more likely favor friends or people who "win them over" vs. the best.  There are large deals and massive firings/hirings at large companies that are made based on someone not liking someone.  I have seen a guy get dissed by my staff then bring in donuts a few times and now he is a nice guy... There is no explaining emotion as it is illogical.
2. Survival:  Before company goals most people worry about themselves first.  So they will say yes to something that gives them more clout or the best chance of getting a promotion even though no is the right choice.  When my company has announced future layoffs, I have seen the very worst of people.  Also note that survival for the most part at work can be money, not just losing the job.  How many companies in the US have outsourced support to terrible remote centers and have had their customers backlash and leave costing them tons of money?  Why did this happen?  Easy.  Because some upper managers have bonuses tied to them reducing short-term costs.  People lose jobs, the company loses customers, but bigwigs get their bonuses.

**When is it good to partake in office politics?**

Anytime you need to do something that fights against other coworkers' emotions or survival mode.

I have written apps for years at my company.  A lot of times if something got released we would get rid of a vendor contract and save hundreds of thousands of dollars a year.  But there would be a group that managed that vendor relationship that might be fired or lose people or get reshuffled.  I have had a few really well made apps die because I just showed the app and the opposing group played politics.

Now in my job I slow play.  I release my apps to key stakeholders and get them used to the functionality.  This requires them to be done well ahead of release plan.  But by getting the apps done early and getting key users on board I let them play the political game for me.

**When else is it good to get into office politics?**

If you need a sales force to sell a phony/crappy product.  Then using your example I would want the most manipulative person leading things - really the best schemers are total psychopaths.  Many of history's most influential leaders were complete psychopaths but just because they gained power doesn't mean they were successful or helped the greater good.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you agree with Plato's statement? I've worked in startup company that had no work politics - just do your job; and I've worked in huge corporations where the HR had been subcontracted to India, and had lots of office politics.

Comment: Personally no matter what I will be ruled by the inferior :)

Answer (score 2):

Whenever someone brings up "office politics" I often feel like the word or phrase itself contaminates the conversation.  For instance, imagine you have a good idea to improve your workplace, and a colleague suggests "before you bring this up with management, you need to get Jane on your side; Jane's been here longer than anyone, and they won't do anything without her approval."

Now, that sounds like politics, but what if Jane is a wise older lady who is level-headed and, despite urgings from her superiors, never wanted to be in management?  What if her gatekeeper-esque status is entirely deserved?  Then it's not politics... it's just the real-life complexities of a workplace.

Things are never as simple as an org structure.  @blankip's answer is spot-on, but don't let the dirty word "politics" soil your world view.

***Edit:*** I didn't answer your question.  When are office politics a good thing?  It's never good or bad by itself.  The people who do all the things that @blankip mentioned are the problem.  The ones who grok that people have emotions and need to be treated kindly, yet the good of the group and the company come first, are the solution.

Comment: I updated the question, you may want to see what has been added.

Comment: @JoeT I literally couldn't tell that I hadn't written that myself.  Your ability to sound like a voice inside my head is a little scary :)

Answer (score 0):

Office politics are often good, it is just that people tend to not define those actions in their minds as office politics.

For instance it is through office politics that your boss can push for you to get a higher raise than the standard and succeed.

It is through office politics that a manager can negotiate getting particular staff assigned to a project. This could be good or bad depending on whether you wanted to be on the project.

It is through office politics that you defend yourself from people who are trying to harm your career.

It is through office politics that you get suggestions for organizational change to be implemented. Again this could be good or bad depending on the change. Or it is through effective use of office politics that you can defend against a bad idea being implemented.

It is through using office politics that you personally can get promoted or get a raise. It is the failure to use office politics that sometimes makes the wrong people get promotions.

It is through office politics that people become more willing to go out of their way to help you because they know you will support them when they need it.